# libxml2.2.dylib creating lot of memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml-parsing, libxml2

It's really hard time for me to remove/avoid leaks while implementing an using **XpathQuery** in my project. Currently I am using libXml2.2.dylib for parsing. When I am checking for the memory leaks using instruments I found lot of leaks in the framework.

[image: libXml2.2.dylib leaks list]

What would be the solution to avoid these leaks. Memory is more concern for us. How can I fix/avoid these buggy leaks?

Comment: @Moshe:  it wouldn't help, libxml2 is a C library.

Comment: can we use any latest version for the libxml2

Comment: Do not rely on Instruments alone - it may introduce false positives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if memory is a major concern, using XML is not your best solution anyway. JSON or a binary format are much more memory efficient.

Second, your trace does not show leaks in the framework. What is shows are leaked objects which whose memory was allocated by the framework. It is more likely that the actual leak is in your code, typically by allocating an object from the library, but then not releasing (or freeing in this case) the object. Look at the stack traces.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue .I got the leaks when I am having empty tags in my documents I clearly observed and modified some code thats it.Basically I rectified in my XpathQuery.m .

```
NSArray *PerformXPathQuery(xmlDocPtr doc, NSString *query)
{
    xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx; 
    xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj;
    /* Create xpath evaluation context */
    xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
    if(xpathCtx == NULL)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    /* Evaluate xpath expression */
    xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression((xmlChar *)[query cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], xpathCtx);
    if(xpathObj == NULL) {
        GLogInfo(@"%@",@"Unable to evaluate XPath");
        xmlXPathFreeObject(xpathObj);
        xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx); 
        return nil;
    }

    xmlNodeSetPtr nodes = xpathObj->nodesetval;
    if (!nodes)
    {
        GLogInfo(@"%@",@"Nodes was nil.");
        xmlXPathFreeObject(xpathObj);
        xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx); 
        return nil;
    }

    NSStringEncoding encoding = cocoaEncodingFromXmlEncodingConst(doc->encoding);
    NSMutableArray *resultNodes = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < nodes->nodeNr; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *nodeDictionary = DictionaryForNode(nodes->nodeTab[i], nil, encoding);
        if (nodeDictionary)
        {
            [resultNodes addObject:nodeDictionary];
        }
    }

    /* Cleanup */
    xmlXPathFreeObject(xpathObj);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx); 
    return resultNodes;
}
```

If your using same class you can use this method absolutely without any doubt/thought on memory leak. Good luck.

Comment: real issue is with
xmlChar *nodeContent = xmlNodeGetContent(currentNode);

Answer (score 0):

if you are using TFHpple then you need to add following code in

> DictionaryForNode

method of

> XPathQuery class

```
if (XML_ELEMENT_NODE != currentNode->type) {
    return nil;
}
```

So your final method should look like

```
NSDictionary *DictionaryForNode(xmlNodePtr currentNode, NSMutableDictionary *parentResult,BOOL parentContent)
{
NSMutableDictionary *resultForNode = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
if (currentNode->name) {
    NSString *currentNodeContent = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char *)currentNode->name
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    resultForNode[@"nodeName"] = currentNodeContent;
}

if (XML_ELEMENT_NODE != currentNode->type) {
    return nil;
}

xmlChar *nodeContent = xmlNodeGetContent(currentNode);

if (nodeContent != NULL) {
    NSString *currentNodeContent = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char *)nodeContent
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if ([resultForNode[@"nodeName"] isEqual:@"text"] && parentResult) {
        if (parentContent) {
            NSCharacterSet *charactersToTrim = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
            parentResult[@"nodeContent"] = [currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charactersToTrim];
            xmlFree(nodeContent);
            return nil;
        }
        if (currentNodeContent != nil) {
            resultForNode[@"nodeContent"] = currentNodeContent;
        }
        return resultForNode;
    } else {
        resultForNode[@"nodeContent"] = currentNodeContent;
    }
    xmlFree(nodeContent);
}

xmlAttr *attribute = currentNode->properties;
if (attribute) {
    NSMutableArray *attributeArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    while (attribute) {
        NSMutableDictionary *attributeDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSString *attributeName = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char *)attribute->name
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (attributeName) {
            attributeDictionary[@"attributeName"] = attributeName;
        }

        if (attribute->children) {
            NSDictionary *childDictionary = DictionaryForNode(attribute->children, attributeDictionary, true);
            if (childDictionary) {
                attributeDictionary[@"attributeContent"] = childDictionary;
            }
        }

        if ([attributeDictionary count] > 0) {
            [attributeArray addObject:attributeDictionary];
        }
        attribute = attribute->next;
    }

    if ([attributeArray count] > 0) {
        resultForNode[@"nodeAttributeArray"] = attributeArray;
    }
}

xmlNodePtr childNode = currentNode->children;
if (childNode) {
    NSMutableArray *childContentArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    while (childNode) {
        NSDictionary *childDictionary = DictionaryForNode(childNode, resultForNode,false);
        if (childDictionary) {
            [childContentArray addObject:childDictionary];
        }
        childNode = childNode->next;
    }
    if ([childContentArray count] > 0) {
        resultForNode[@"nodeChildArray"] = childContentArray;
    }
}

xmlBufferPtr buffer = xmlBufferCreate();
xmlNodeDump(buffer, currentNode->doc, currentNode, 0, 0);
NSString *rawContent = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char *)buffer->content encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (rawContent != nil) {
    resultForNode[@"raw"] = rawContent;
}
xmlBufferFree(buffer);
return resultForNode;
}
```